# Angularjs 1.0 $http is passed to a controller without any definition for it

Tags: angularjs

I'm just a newbie to Angular.

This is probably the most basic question but I cannot seem understand the concept of it.

**$http** - I understand the purpose of it.

In order to keep the controllers light we shouldn't write $http() on the controllers. So they have to inject it in to the controller. I can understand up to this.

I have a project where they have just injected `$http` to the controller without defining what `$http` should do.

It says this is how we can define a $http.

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "welcome.htm"
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
});
```

What I assumed is for every controller that takes $http as a parameter we have to define that $http using this syntax. Or there should be some generalized definition for what $http should do.

But to my surprise I didn't find any such definition in my project.

My question is what will happen when I don't define $http but just simply pass it to the controller as a parameter and how does that work?

Comment: you really need to just do some reading on the angular documentation

Answer (score 1):

$http is a AngularJs service (basically a wrapper on XMLHttpRequest), with which you can make http calls like $http.get, $http.post. You need to inject this into your controller to make use of it. Once you have injected this into controller, make use of $http.get or post syntax to make calls to your own pages or API.

In short, you will need to write code to make get or post calls using $http in your controller or factories or wherever you wish to

Please refer to [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) from AngularJs org. for more info on this:

Answer (score 0):

> what will happen when I don't define $http but just simply pass it to
>   the controller as a parameter

**Just look into this Example :**

```
var protocol = "$http"; // suppose getting "$http" from $stateParams or $routParams
protocol({
method : "GET",
url : "welcome.htm"
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
});
```

It will give you the below error as `$http` is a Angular Service we can not use it as a variable.

> TypeError: protocol is not a function